# django: get ordered list of related objects (different models)

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I've got stuck with django model queries.

My Models:

```
class ProjectCategory(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(_('Categoryname'), max_length=250)

class Reference(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(_('Title'),max_length=250)
    category=models.ForeignKey(ProjectCategory)
    start_date=models.DateTimeField(_('Start date'),
                                help_text= _(u'Starting date of the project'),
                                )
    end_date=models.DateTimeField(_('End date'),
                              help_text= _(u'Project end date'),)

class Project(Reference):
   size=models.CharField(_('size'),max_length=250)
```

I need a list of all categories (orderd by name) and all its References and Projects (orderd by start_date.

e.g

```
Category1
-Reference 1 1.1.2012
-Project 1 1.1.2013
-Reference 2 1.1.2014

Category2
-Project 2 1.1.2000
-Reference 3 1.1.2001
```

How to build the query and the template?

Answer (score 1):

The query is straight forward one:

```
categories = ProjectCategory.objects.select_related().all().order_by("name")
```

Within the template, you simply have to iterate through the `category_set` since both `Reference` and `Project` should be found there. A `dictsort` should take care of ordering within the template:

```
{% for c in categories %}
  <h2> {{ c }} </h2>
  <ul>
  {% for r in c.category_set.all|dictsort:"start_date" %}
    <li> {{ r }} </li>
  {% endfor %}
  <ul>
{% endfor %}
```